# Are Thomas and family illegal immigrants?

Tags: skins

If they are illegal immigrants, how does Thomas get work (including at a legitimate supermarket) and a place at school?

If they are legal immigrants, how did they find a way to legally enter and then legally stay long-term in the UK? (That is, how did they find a way to be legal immigrants?)

---

In S03E03 (2009), Thomas's passport shows a photo of a completely different person with "Nom de Famille" "Lumumba", "Nom" "Din", and "Date de naissance" "24 Juin 1963":

[image]

Thomas is probably around 18 or 19. The [actor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merveille_Lukeba) who plays him was born 1990 and would've been around 19 when S03 aired. Thomas:

[image]

So I think it's safe to say Thomas couldn't possibly have entered the UK legally with that passport.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the second part of your question. If they're legal immigrants, they don't *need* to "find a way" - they just enter the UK through normal, legal channels, and they then have the right to stay for as long as they want.

Comment: "*Your child can go to school, even if you have an immigration status with the ‘no recourse to public funds (NRPF)’ condition, or you are undocumented."* - https://www.london.gov.uk/programmes-strategies/communities-and-social-justice/migrant-londoners-hub/education-and-training/primary-and-secondary-education-5-16-year-olds

Comment: Looking at his profile on the wiki and the e4 website, the implication seems to be that Thomas is a *documented* asylum seeker claiming to be a minor. He flew from the Congo to the UK and is now the anchor being used to bring his family over

Comment: @F1Krazy: How did they find a way to be legal immigrants? (How did "they just enter the UK through normal, legal channels"?)

Comment: @Valorum: That quote seems to be for 5-16 year-olds only (which Thomas was not). Children's Legal Centre ([2013](https://t.ly/DW8D3)): *Access to free education is permitted by law for those in compulsory education, but for those wishing to study after the age of 16, immigration status will often be a barrier to their doing so. ... local authorities are not obliged to provide school places for 16-18 year olds and current regulations make clear that a learner must be lawfully resident in the UK in order to secure a free place in further education.*

Comment: In any case, as mentioned, Thomas finds work at various places, including most notably at a legitimate supermarket.

Comment: @Valorum: "is now the anchor being used to bring his family over" I don't think so because his mother and two younger siblings show up very soon (within a few days) after he arrives. Also, he's surprised when they show up early ("But you're not coming until next week")

Comment: @user103496 You just buy a plane ticket and then apply for a visa at the other end, the same way you'd migrate to any other country in the world.

Comment: @F1Krazy: I hope you're joking and not just completely ignorant.

Comment: Ah, I've just seen the edit to the question, my apologies. I'm pretty sure you've probably answered your own question there, to be fair.

Comment: Yes, that should be posted as a self-answer, not as an edit to the question.

Comment: @Valorum: How so? That was merely the passport he showed Johnny. (1) He could still have entered the UK legally though not by that passport. In which case my question as stated above was, "how did they find a way to legally enter and then legally stay long-term in the UK?" (2) While if he entered illegally, my question as stated above was, "how does Thomas get work (including at a legitimate supermarket) and a place at school?"

Comment: @user103496 - The fact that he has a fake passport (or possibly a real passport that looks nothing like him) would strongly imply that he's lied to immigration about his age

Comment: @Valorum: He could merely have been using it to deceive Johnny, who isn't exactly very smart. It seems impossible that that passport could've been used for any legitimate purpose.